# Creating an ascending number generator for Rails form

Tags: ruby, forms, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I've looked at forums, worked through tutorials and looked in the Rails guides but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to create a security application for a company I work for and I am creating the report form. I would like the reports to be numbered with an ascending number but am not sure what to search for or do to accomplish this.

I am using PostgreSQL as my database for both dev and prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `id` column if it is set up as the primary key (as it normally is). It would be unique to every report, never repeat, and increment by one with every new report.

Or you can make a column just for the report # and use:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  colname SERIAL
);
```

this is equal to doing:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

This will allow you to set the starting number via:

```
SELECT setval('colname', 42, false);
```

The `false` means the first number handed out will be 42, not 43. If left out or set to true it will return 43 as the first value in the sequence.

An important aspect of sequences in Postgres is that a new number is handed out every time, even if that row fails to stay because of a transaction failure. So you could end of with missing numbers in the sequence.

Be sure and read this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html

If this is a problem you might just want to do all of this in Rails by doing something like:

```
next_number = Report.select(:id).order('id DESC').limit(1).pluck(:id).first + 1
```

and have a unique constraint on the column to ensure no duplicate numbers.

For other DB's see this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: great idea however the reports start at a specific number and work up is there a way to start an ID at a specific number and ascend from there?

Comment: You need to expand and clarify your answer then. So will the very first repot on the DB start at a number, let's say 344, and then just all go up one form there? Will the numbers always be unique across the entire table? Or will there by multiple reports numbered "10" if they are the 10th report in a series?

Comment: my apologies, I'm new to the forum world. Yes each report will be 100% unique and will not have any duplicates. it is essentially like a police report number.

Comment: See my edit. You will also want to enforce `unique` so that no number is ever duplicated, how ever the DB you are using does that. What Database are you using?

Comment: Bah! I just reread and see that you said Postgres as your DB. You WILL need to enforce uniqueness as Postgres does not. I'll edit my answer since that link does not cover Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! It was very useful and everything is working now!